# How to list all suggestions and filtered suggestions based on user input using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to show all available usernames when user types @ in input field and filtered usernames when user enters anything after @ character.

I have implemented like below,

```
class UserMention extends React.purecomponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: '',
            user_mention: false,
        };
        this.user='';
     }

     user_list = [
         {name: 'John smith'},
         {name: 'Jenna surname2'},
         {name: 'Tuija rajala'},
     ]; 

     get_user = s => s.includes('@') && s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('@') + 
     1).split(' ')[0];

     handle_input_change = (event) => {
         let user_mention;
         this.user = this.get_user(event.target.value);

         if (event.target.value.endsWith('@')) {
             user_mention = true;
         } else {
            user_mention = false;
         }

         this.setState({
             user_mention: user_mention,
             [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
         });
      };

      get_text_with_user_mention = (text, selected_user) => {
          let user_name = selected_user;
          let text_without_user_mention;
          text_without_user_mention = text.slice(0, 
          text.lastIndexOf('@'));
          return text_without_user_mention + user_name;
      };

      handle_select_value = (selected_user) => {
          let text;
          text = this.get_text_with_user_mention(this.state.text, 
          selected_user);
          this.setState({
              text: text,
              user_mention: false,
          });
          this.user = false;
      };

      render = () => {
          let suggested_values = [];
          if (this.state.user_mention) {
              suggested_values = this.user_list
                 .map((o) => { return {user_name: o.user_name};});
          }
          if (this.user) {
              suggested_values = this.user_list
                  .filter(user => user.user_name.indexOf(this.user) !== 
                  -1)
                  .map((o) => {return {user_name: o.user_name};});
       }
       return (
            <input
                required
                name="text"
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                type="text"/>
            {this.state.user_mention &&
                <SelectInput
                    on_change={this.handle_select_value}
                    values={suggested_values}/>}
            {this.user &&
                <SelectInput
                    on_change={this.handle_select_value}
                    values={suggested_values}/>}
        );
    };
}
```

As you see from above code, i am modifying suggested_values based on this.user and this.state.user_mention state.  Can someone help me refactor or modify this  a bit more nicer. thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please check out my solution below and let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by doing something like this.

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-kgm2h

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

```
class UserMention extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      user_list: [
        { name: "John smith" },
        { name: "Jenna surname2" },
        { name: "Tuija rajala" }
      ],
      suggestions: []
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const { user_list } = this.state;
    //show all user suggestions
    if (value.includes("@") && value.indexOf("@") === value.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        text: value,
        suggestions: [...this.state.user_list]
      });
      //show matching user suggesstions
    } else if (value.includes("@") && value.length > 1) {
      const stringAfterAt = value.slice(value.indexOf("@") + 1).toLowerCase();
      const newSuggestions = user_list.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(stringAfterAt);
      });
      this.setState({
        text: value,
        suggestions: newSuggestions
      });
      //display no users if they do not use the @ symbol
    } else {
      this.setState({
        text: value,
        suggestions: []
      });
    }
  };

  createSuggestionsList = () => {
    const { suggestions } = this.state;
    return suggestions.map(user => {
      return <div>{user.name}</div>;
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          required
          name="text"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          type="text"
        />
        {this.createSuggestionsList()}
        {/* <SelectInput value={this.state.suggestions}/> */}
      </div>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<UserMention />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I'm not entirely sure how you want to render the suggested users, but you can always just pass down `this.state.suggestions` as a prop to the `SelectInput` component.

Main takeaway is to use an additional `array` in our `state` for `suggestions` and update it as the user types into the `input`. We call `{this.createSuggestionsList()}` inside `render` to dynamically create the markup for each suggested user. Or as mentioned above, just pass down the `suggestions` as a `prop`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer :) this works perfect when user types @ in the input field but i want to cover also this usecase  where user types "i am @user1" or "i am @" i want to show suggestions in that case too... :)

Comment: @oh for sure! let me see what i can do :)

Comment: thanks a lot :) this works like a charm and only one state to use.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user. You're welcome! I'm glad this was helpful to you and yup, I think just having one state makes it cleaner to follow :)

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach using React hooks, instead of classes. If you've never worked with hooks, give it a try. You will enjoy it. It's much simpler in my opinion.

[image]

I also added a `username` property. It's much better if you work with a string that doesn't allow spaces when you're tagging someone. You can also display the full name with spaces along with the `username`, if you wish.

**Ex:**

`John Smith (@johnsmith)`

```js
function App() {

  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const [userList,setUserList] = React.useState([
    {name: 'John smith', username:'johnsmith'},
    {name: 'Jenna surname2', username:'jennasurname2'},
    {name: 'Tuija rajala', username:'tuijarajala'}
   ]
  );
  const [showSuggestions,setShowSuggestions] = React.useState(false);
  
  const [suggestionList,setSuggestionList] = React.useState(
    ['johnsmith','jennasurname2','tuijarajala']
  );
  
  function onChange(event) {
    const regexp = /@[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    if (regexp.test(event.target.value)) {
      setShowSuggestions(true);
    }
    else {
      setShowSuggestions(false);
    }
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }
  
  function focusInput() {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <input ref={inputRef} type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={onChange}/>
      {showSuggestions && 
        <Suggestions
          inputValue={inputValue}
          suggestionList={suggestionList}
          applyMention={onChange}
          focusInput={focusInput}
        />
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Suggestions(props) {
  
  function selectSuggestion(username) {
    const regexp = /@[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    const newValue = props.inputValue.replace(regexp,username + ' ');
    props.applyMention({target: {value: newValue}}); // THIS MIMICS AN ONCHANGE EVENT
    props.focusInput();
  }
  
  const suggestionItems = props.suggestionList.map((item) => 
    <div className="item" onClick={()=>selectSuggestion('@' + item)}>@{item}</div>
  );
  
  return(
    <div className="container">
      {suggestionItems}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 150px;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover {
  color: blue;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) this is missing use case where user types "i am @user1" or "i am @" i want to show suggestions in that case too...

Comment: I've updated my answer and added this feature. You still need to implement the username filtering feature though. Right now it shows all username options. But you got that code already. Just need to tweak it a little bit and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer the other solution seemed easy for me to use into my code. but upvoting your answer too :)

Comment: No problem! Thanks. If you're not familiar to React Hooks, give it try. It's much cleaner than working with classes. You'll see!